# Reading data from PNG or JPG file into R

Tags: r, image

I have a PNG and JPG file of a data table, specifically:

[image]
<sub>(source: [njdc.com](https://img.njdc.com/media/media/2015/09/01/wholechart.png))</sub>

I'm trying to read in this data table into R so I can perform data analysis on the data. However, I'm not seeing how to do this. I can read in the file using the 'png' and 'jpeg' packages, but these do not create a data frame of the data table shown in the image. Is there any way I can get the data table into R?

Comment: Honestly, its probably easier to just transcribe this by hand or pay someone else to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Not perfect but:

```
2.6 I HI Yes JJ Yes JJ Yes V No H Difficult H Difficult W 14days J
8.1 I MA I Yes JJ Yes J No v No V Difficult V Difficult V None
4.2 I NY I Yes Yes Yes ‘V No H Difficult H Prohibited ‘ None
4.4 - CT Yes Yes No No Difficult Moderate None
5.3 - RI NoA Yes No I No H Difficult V Moderate r 7days
NJ l Yes Yes No No Difficult Difficult 7days
NH No No No Yes Moderate “figqfifi:gt None

MN No No No V No ' Moderate Moderate ’ 7days J

CA r Yes JJ Yes JJ Yes v No" V Difficult “Prohibited“‘v 10 days J
m IA , Yes Yes No I No V Moderate Moderate r 3days
a IL FOID Yes** No No" Moderate Prohibited 72 hours
WA No No No No" Easy “figqfifiggt None

m Dc No J Yes JJ Yes ‘V No H Difficult H Prohibited W 10 days J
m NE Yes JJ Yes J No No Easy fig£fi£gt None
w No No No ' No ' “bruit“? tgqtergtt
MD Yes Yes Yes No Difficult Difficult 7days

WI No No No Yesf Easy “figqfifi:gt 48 hours J
SD No No No Yes Moderate flgqfifiggt None
VA No No No No" Moderate “figqfifi:gt None
DE No Yes No V No H Difficult ' Ngqojeirgzjit None
TX No No No Yes Easy Moderatei None
ME No No No I No ‘ Moderate fig£fi£gt None
OH No No No Yest Easy “figqfilei;gt None
GR No J Yes** J No No" Moderate figqfiierggit None
PA No J Yes J No Yes Moderate qufifigj'i} None
KS No No No Yes Moderate higqfifigjit None
CO No Yes No Yes Moderate qufifigj'i} None
ND No No No Yesf Moderate Moderate None

FL No No No Yes Easy ' Prohibited fr 3days J
Ml Yes JJ Yes JJ Yes Yes Moderate L flgqfileiggt A None
No Yes JJ Yes J No Yes Easy higqfifigjit None
GA No No No Yes Moderate Moderate None
UT No No No Yes Moderate Moderate None
IN No No No Yes Moderate Moderate None
KY No No No Yes Easy fig£fi£gt None
NV No No No Yes Easy fig£fi£gt None
A2 No No No 'izqterz‘lt
ID No No No No" Easy fig£fi£gt None
WV No No No Yes Easy higqfifigjit None
Mo No No No Yest Moderate Moderate None
so No No No Yes Easy ' Prohibited ‘ None
TN No No No Yes Easy L Moderate A None
NM No No No No" Easy flgqfifiggt None
OK No No No Yes Easy Moderate None
MT No No No Yes Moderate “figqfifiggt None
wv No No No that
AR No No No YesAA Moderate Prohibited None
AL No No No Yes Moderate . flgqfifiggt 1 None
M8 No No No Yes Easy “figqfilei;gt None
LA No No No Yes Easy “figqfifiggt None
AK No No No we $202.12?
```

Sometimes data acquisition ain't pretty.

Done via https://www.newocr.com/ (i am not affiliated with them in any way, shape or form, but I use them occassionally for stuff like this). You may get better results if you do better desaturation and sharpening than I did.